# Using file name in a function argument

Tags: r

I have two csv-files for example named abc.csv and efg.csv. Im trying to create a function that choses the correct file by typing files name to function argument. Then it should return the first row of that data frame.

I have tried this, but there is probably something wrong in the way using [[" "]]-marks.

```
function(x)

{ if x == [["abc"]] return( a <- read.csv2(file = "abc.csv", header = FALSE, sep = ",",
                                           stringsAsFactors = FALSE) )
  else return(a <- read.csv2(file = "efg.csv", header = FALSE, sep = ",",
                             stringsAsFactors = FALSE))

  y <- a[1,]
  paste(y)
```

Comment: Where are the files stored? Are they always in the same directory? Working directory? Do you need to change directories at some point?

Comment: sorry I don't understand your question. Do you mean the file directory in r?

Comment: The files are in the same working directory.

Comment: Don't use `return`, almost never needed. No need to use `[[]]`. Simple if-else might suffice. `[[]]` is reserved for subsetting which is not being done here. I assume you wanted to use it on `list.files` but then pattern would be better.

Comment: Maybe something like this? `file_chooser <- function(file_name=NULL){

 if(grepl("xyz",file_name)){
   read.csv(file_name)[1,]
 }
 else{
   read.csv("abc")[1,]
 }
}`? xyz is the target, abc otherwise.